# Compare one field with another field of csv file that conatin 4 values that are comma separated

Tags: python-3.x, csv, deep-learning

I have a csv file, which contain 2 fields, one is answer field and another is option field, the option field contain 4 options which is comma separated. I want compare the answer with the 4 options within the option field.I have to do it using python

[image]

Comment: Please provide code attempt...
If you don't know where to start, look into : https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html

Comment: also checkout pandas - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/10min.html